# Skipped installing realm-cocoa.framework binary due to the error:

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, carthage

when I try to add my dependencies using Carthage I got this error

```
*** Downloading realm-cocoa.framework binary at "v3.7.4"
*** Downloading RxSwift.framework binary at "Zürich"
***  Skipped installing realm-cocoa.framework binary due to the error:
    "Incompatible Swift version - framework was built with 4.1 (swiftlang-902.0.48 clang-902.0.37.1) and the local version is 4.1.2 (swiftlang-902.0.54 clang-902.0.39.2)."

    Falling back to building from the source
A shell task (/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -workspace /Users/safoinemoncefamine/AppWink/carthage\ frameworks/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Alamofire.xcworkspace CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES -list) failed with exit code 72:
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

this is my CartFile

```
github "Moya/Moya"
github "rs/SDWebImage"
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAdMobBinary.json"
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAnalyticsBinary.json"
github "SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD"
github "realm/realm-cocoa"
```

Comment: There is swift version compatibility issue. Your framework is build on swift 4.1 whereas your project is using swift 4.1.2. Try to use latest version of framework or downgrade your project swift language version support.